# How to use cucumber table when it is code driven

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I want to use single row under examples in cucumber like below:
**Examples**:
| **data1** | **data2**|**paymentOp**| 
| MySql | uk1 |??????????| 
Where paymentOp is a number which I am getting from java method which has List as an argument. The method returns each of the numbers which I want to pass it under paymentOp.

There is an absolute way to iterate it by copy the row and paste it again in the table but I don't want that because the method has a dynamic result which may return 2 or 5 set of numbers.

Is it possible to achieve it using Karate?
How to proceed further. Any lead here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `Examples:` with dynamic behavior. Please read this example (especially the second one): https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature

Since you have difficulties reading the docs and examples (:P) here is a simple example. Take some time to understand it carefully.

```
Background:
* def data = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

Scenario Outline:
* match data.<key> == <value>

Examples:
| key   | value |
| one   | 1     |
| two   | 2     |
| three | 3     |
```

Comment: Thanks for the information passed. I think in my case, the data elements are dynamic so it may have 2/5/6 values in it like below:
[ {
    "payment_id": 1
  },
  {
    "payment_id": 3
  },
  {
    "payment_id": 5
  },
  {
    "payment_id": 6
  }
]
I need to pass each payment_id as a parameter in the Example table. Since its database response and it can be varied for other regions.
So, I am stuck here. Hope you understand the situation here :)

Comment: To give the thought more clear to the above, What I have the situation is like the data json may have 3 /4/5 key-value pair depend upon the database method readRows() result.

Comment: @RanjanGupta it would have been nice if you provided this clarity in your original question. please refer to this answer and let me know if you have more questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019349/143475

Comment: you can use [qaf-bdd](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) which supports [custom data provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario.html#data-driven-scenario) and [support for web-services](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws#qaf-support-ws) automation