# How to generate more than one random UUID and use in scenario outline examples in karate

Tags: karate

I am new to Karate API, pardon me for the mistakes if any.

I want to generate multiple random UUID and then use them in scenario outline examples

Example:
Background:

- def UUID = function() {return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ''}

Scenario outline: to do post call
Given url 'http://localhost:8080'

- def UID = UUID()
- print UID

And request {CID:"", name :""}

When method POST

Then status 201

Examples:

|CID| name|

|UID1| james|

|UID2| rahul|

Here in above 'Examples' I wanted to use randomly generated UUID in data table of examples so that I can run multiple scenarios for UUID with one POST API call.
First question: How can I generate multiple random UUID ?
Second question: once multiple UUID gets generated how can i call in scenario outline examples and use them?
Can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Marked answer as accepted .

Answer (score 2):

Please try running the following simple example.

```
Feature:

Background:
* def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }

Scenario Outline:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* param foo = uuid()
* request { item: '#(item)' }
* method post

Examples:
| item   |
| first  |
| second |
```

It will make 2 requests, and each request will use a different `param` called "foo" and the URL will be like this:

```
https://httpbin.org/anything?foo=c1b6ab3d-5952-413b-827c-d9579a0a93b6
```

So it is simple. Think of the `Examples:` as like a "loop". Each time the `Scenario Outline` runs, we are calling the `uuid()` function again, which will return a different, random value.

Comment: Hey Peter Thomas, Thank you for the above answer but its not resolved my question 
I was looking for the output :
1. how to generate multiple UUID 
2. How can I call the UUID in data table of examples instead of calling in URL as parameter

Comment: @chadee the answer to your second question is no, you cannot do "dynamic" stuff in the `Examples:` data table. please read this to understand more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52166427/143475 you seem to be insisting that random values be inside the table, but it is fine to have it in the `Scenario Outline` body. if you don't like it, please look for another tool. the answer to your first question is in my answer. did you try running it ? please run it - and if it still doesn't do what you are asking, please look for another tool, karate is not a good fit for you.

Comment: Okay Thank you Peter Thomas, will try  the first answer .