# Can I use for loop in karate?

Tags: for-loop, karate

I am using get request for getting json response. And it is dynamic. My response looks like this.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Jack",
            "gender": "male"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jill",
            "gender": "female"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I use id from this response and put that id in 'for loop' to execute delete method?
Given path 'profile/delete/id'
And if I can then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
* def result = call read('delete.feature') response.data
```

And in `delete.feature` you will be able to refer to the `id` variable directly.