# Karate.call is not working in the for loop, getting polygot exception

Tags: javascript, api, automation, karate

Scenario: Test
* def userList = Java.type('aws.iamUtil.users.ListUsers')

- json userID = userList.listAwsIamUserId()
- def eSearch = read(pathConfig.featureDir.elasticSearchFeatures + 'ElasticSearch.feature@elasticSearch')
- def fun =
  """
  function(array) {
  var temp = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  temp = { principalId: array[i] };
  karate.call(eSearch);
  }
  return temp;
  }
  """
- def result  = fun(userID)

Result:
js failed:

> > > > 

01: fun(userID)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (call) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@445dc8dc failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)]], arguments: [JavaObject[classpath:features/api/elastic_search/ElasticSearch.feature (com.intuit.karate.core.Feature)] (HostObject)])

- .:anonymous(Unnamed:5)

Comment: Resolved! For answer refer below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843184/can-i-use-for-loop-in-karate