# Karate - Conditional logic with string and array

Tags: soap, cucumber, conditional-statements, karate

This question derives from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984158/karate-how-to-loop-soap-request-with-values-received-from-a-response-array) asked earlier. I am making a Soap request, and I am receiving the response as either an Array, or String.

```
[print] [   "M4205N",   "M4206U" ]

[print] M5967H
```

When I get the response as an array, I figured out how to loop through it, and pass the values to another request. However, sometimes the response will come back as a single Code, and it will be returned as a String. In that case, I cannot perform the same logic as I did with the array. I've read about [Karate conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic), but I cannot figure out how to make it do what I want.

I want to do something like this:
If the response is returned as a String, then call this method with the one value. 
If the response is returned as an array, then call this method and pass each value from the array.

This is one of the ways I had in mind, but it does not work because of the Type difference:

```
* def memberCodes = memberCodes.size() > 1 ? karate.mapWithKey(memberCodes, 'memberCode') : {}
* def result = call read('OtherRequest.feature') memberCodes
```

This works if the response is returned as an array, but obviously if it's returned as a String it will break.

What is the right way to perform this conditional logic? Also, please [refer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984158/karate-how-to-loop-soap-request-with-values-received-from-a-response-array) for more context if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. This check should work for testing if (not) a string:

```
* def memberCodes = typeof memberCodes != 'string' ? karate.mapWithKey(memberCodes, 'memberCode') : {}
```

Also refer this somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543843/143475

Comment: Great, that worked. Thank you!

I tweaked the logic a little:
* def memberCodes = typeof memberCodes != 'string' ? karate.mapWithKey(memberCodes, 'memberCode') : {memberCode: memberCodes}

When the response is returned as a String, this will convert it into a map. That way I can call the same feature file after:

* def result = call read('OtherRequest.feature') memberCodes