# Karate - Calling another feature file with dynamic param does not print a response

Tags: rest, cucumber, karate

I am having trouble yielding a response when calling a feature file from another feature file and passing a dynamic param. I am using the same logic from a previous answer when passing params to another feature file. [Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037707/karate-conditional-logic-with-string-and-array) However, this time it is not a SOAP call, it is a REST call.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

---

first.feature:

This first call (without passing a param) works fine, and I am able to capture the response, and store the orderItemId in a variable. I need to then pass this ID to another endpoint.

```
* def result = call read('classpath:order/createOrder.feature@createOrder')
    * print result.response
    * def orderItemId = get result..orderItemId
    * def orderItemId = typeof orderItemId != 'string' ? karate.mapWithKey(orderItemId, 'id') : {id: orderItemId}
```

This looks something like {"id": "test758887"}

```
    * print orderItemId
```

This next call I am passing the orderItemId to another reusable feature file, and it works successfully.

```
    * def hello = call read('details.feature') orderItemId
```

After this call is done, I see the response in my IDE console with the proper json, **however when I try to print the response from the first feature file, it yields no results.**

```
    * print hello.response
```

Here is what it looks like in console:
[image]

I am trying to grab the "status" value, so I can create some polling logic.

When I try to print just 'hello' (* print hello), I see content, but it is a huge json with all sorts of data that is not pertinent to the call I just made, such as all of my common variables I've created in feature files, as well as the karate config. Very strange.

---

details.feature is very simple, and looks something like this:

```
 Given url msURL
 And path authGroupName, sender, 'orders', id
 When method get
 Then status 200
```

Am I properly making this call? Or is there something I need to change? Or is this an issue with Karate? Thank you in advance.

Comment: follow this process and either you or me will get the answer in 5 minutes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the answer :) It works.